# Most optimal pizza type or style for home oven?

Tags: pizza

I have an electric oven with a "broiler" function. Its not bad, but temperature-wise it doesn't get close to the 450°C required for "real" neapolitan style pizza. I think it is below 250°C on the highest setting.

So I was wondering, since I can never achieve real pizza with what I have on hand, are there styles of pizza, I could actually nail with my oven?

I was thinking, that Sicily style and other deep dish pizzas should be a good fit for an oven with low maximum temperature?

What about Roman style pizza?

Comment: Put some tag because all your pizza styles are obscure. At least for me as Italian, ignore this if I am wrong. I know an answer but it might be trivial. Forget getting a wood oven type of results, or something like the pizza of most pizzerias. Italians in their kitchen do something similar to what seems generally called American pizza, more or less ticker and more or less crispy depending on taste, and well, oven performance.

Comment: Would you say what you do at home is comparable to Sicilian "pizza"? Do you fry the dough slightly? I would like to read your answer on this. Just describe what you do at home!

Comment: You can bake neapolitan style pizza. It'll just take a few minutes longer. Get yourself a pizza stone.

Comment: See @moscafi answer. I personally do a dough for pizza, recipes vary slightly in ratios and sometimes are more specific when it comes to flour.  The results depends on timing and oven as well the amount of dough laid on the pan. Cooking: gas oven, a small electric one usually used for breakfast, and few days ago I even tried iron pan on stove.  That day it was the most satisfactory though I had to finish the top in the small electric oven by grill.

Comment: Some pizza dough formulas to try. https://1drv.ms/b/s!AnPAN_4gx2Z-gzl4nYayN_NgyCUC

Answer (score 5):

"Optimal" is a matter of taste and opinion with regard to this question.  I am not sure we can answer that. I would start with a calibrated oven thermometer and crank your oven, so you know what temperature you can achieve.  In my home oven, I can achieve a decent Neapolitan style pizza using a pizza steel and oven temps slightly below 260C (500F).  This is well-below the ideal temperature, but with a long pre-heat, and longer than typical cooking time, it works out well.  Alternately, there are thick crust sheet pan pizzas, deep dish pizzas (Chicago style), and pizzas that can be made in a cast iron pan...all of which should be easy to do in any home oven.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that professionally made Chicago style pizza is made with lower temperatures, comparable to home ovens?